# Does Sonatype Open Source Nexus supports Maven 3?

Tags: maven, nexus

We are thinking about to build up a Sonatype Nexus OOS server. In all documentation, it is mentioned that it supports maven 2, but its never mentioned if it's support Maven 3.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally Maven 2 is a complete rewrite of the Maven 1 system and not directly backwards compatible. The dependency system format introduced by Maven 2 has been used from version 2 and up, including version 3.X.X.

So Yes, Maven 3 is also supported.

In fact, the Nexus OSS v3 [mentions specifically in their documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/maven-repositories#MavenRepositories-MavenRepositoryFormat) this is the case:

> Apache Maven created the most widely used repository format in the Java development ecosystem with the release of Apache Maven 2. It is used by all newer versions of Apache Maven and many other tools including Apache Ivy, Gradle, sbt, Eclipse Aether and Leiningen.